# Animations covering up content

Tags: html, css

I finished putting all my content onto my html. After that I went to create the background, I want a space type of background so I googled what to do. I used code I found to create a background. My page went from having content on it to having no content but showing the animated space background only, with a blank footer. Anyway around this to where I can have my animation and my content on the page.

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what you have done, can you put the code here? one quick way I think is to just make your background div absolute and give it z-index:-1 left:0 top:0